# Getting the string out of an LLVM string constant

Tags: ocaml, llvm

I am using the LLVM bindings to read an LLVM bitcode file in OCaml. In that file there is a global string constant defined like this:

```
@.str1 = private unnamed_addr constant [6 x i8] c"x > y\00", align 1
```

I have an `llvalue` that corresponds to this constant and I want to get at the string `"x > y"` from that. One thing I can do is to use `string_of_llvalue (global_initializer the_constant)` to get the string `"c\"x > y \\00\""`, then extract the part between the quotes and then parse the escape sequences within that part. However that does not seem like a very good solution to me.

The C++ API has the function `constantDataSequential::getAsString` that I could use to access the constant's string value, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to accomplish the same thing using the OCaml bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of the question, parsing the result of `string_of_llvalue` was indeed the only option other than writing one's own binding for `getAsString`.

However, in more recent versions of the OCaml bindings, this can much more easily accomplished by `string_of_const`. It takes an `llvalue` and returns a `Some` containing the string contents if the given `llvalue` is a string constant and `None` otherwise.